# I'm trying to compile a simple HelloJNI program using ndk in Android Studio and get an error

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When trying to compile my app I'm getting this error.

> com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Compiler exited with error code 1: C:\Users\esotsm54\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-gcc -xc --sysroot=C:\Users\esotsm54\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64 -v -dD -E Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=C:\Users\esotsm54\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\x86_64-linux-android-gcc Target: x86_64-linux-android Configured with: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/gcc/toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.9/configure --prefix=/tmp/0aa76abad9b5b49476dd74e65f11e7fa --target=x86_64-linux-android --host=x86_64-pc-mingw32msvc --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpc=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-cloog=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-isl=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-ppl=/buildbot/tmp/build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-isl-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lstdc++ -lm -static' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=intel --with-fpmath=sse --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-bionic-libs --enable-libatomic-ifuncs=no --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/0aa76abad9b5b49476dd74e65f11e7fa --with-sysroot=/tmp/0aa76abad9b5b49476dd74e65f11e7fa/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.25 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.9 --with-gdb-version=none --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/0aa76abad9b5b49476dd74e65f11e7fa/include/c++/4.9.x --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-libcilkrts --disable-libsanitizer --enable-gold --enable-eh-frame-hdr-for-static --enable-graphite=yes --with-isl-version=0.11.1 --with-cloog-version=0.18.0 --program-transform-name='s&^&x86_64-linux-android-&' --enable-gold=default Thread model: posix gcc version 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease) (GCC) COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_IGNORE_DEFINITIONS_START' '-mtune=intel' '-march=x86-64' cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix c:\users\esotsm54\appdata\local\android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/ -isysroot C:Usersesotsm54AppDataLocalAndroidSdkndk-bundle/platforms/android-23/arch-x86_64 -D ___CIDR_IGNORE_DEFINITIONS_START C:\Users\esotsm54\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file0 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mbionic -fPIC -mtune=intel -march=x86-64 -dD x86_64-linux-android-gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Comment: And the code the compiler didn't like looks like *what*?